# Convert object key to array with values number of key with Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an object with products:

```
products: {
  bread: 1,
  milk: 2,
  cheese: 2,
  chicken: 1,
}
```

I would like to have an array with the name of products like this:

```
products: ['bread', 'milk', 'milk', 'cheese', 'cheese', 'chicken']
```

I was trying to use `lodash` with `reduce` method but I don't know how to "multiply" this product in array.

I think this is not a good idea:

```
_.reduce(products, (result, value, key) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
   result.push(key);
  }
  return result;
}, [])
```

So if anyone could help, I will be grateful.

Comment: Why is your solution not a good idea? Edit: _If you wanted you could reduce twice (replace the for loop with a reduce)?_

Comment: your solution seems perfectly valid, I wouldn't have done that any other way (except not using lodash because I don't really dig it, but if you're using it anyway... why not).

Comment: If you don't like using `for` loop to "multiply" products, you may use [`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) method instead

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) over the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the object

```js
const products = {
  bread: 1,
  milk: 2,
  cheese: 2,
  chicken: 1,
}

const output = Object.entries(products).flatMap(([k, v]) => Array(v).fill(k))

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

With lodash you can iterate the array with `_.flatMap()`. Create the the callback using `_.overArgs()` that will pass the value (via `_.identity()`) and the key (wrapped with `_.constant()`) to `_.times()`:

```js
const obj = {
  products: {
    bread: 1,
    milk: 2,
    cheese: 2,
    chicken: 1,
  }
}

const result = _.flatMap(obj.products, _.overArgs(_.times, [_.identity, _.constant]))
  
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```